# PHP tables causing issues

Tags: php, html, html-table

ive been finishing a school project which needs to get a response from a server so ive written some php code. Ive got everything to align up with tables but when I implement it, I get a Giant gap in code. Has anyone seen this before, I know its the  tabs causing this but idk why they keep messing it up, ive tried to move them, but everything in them and more with no luck. below is the outcome of this code,

thank you for your help. [Code’s outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLAIk.png)

```
<?php

  // create short variable names
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$zip = $_POST['zip'];
$state = $_POST['state'];
$outdate = $_POST['outdate'];
$indate = $_POST['indate'];
$numberofpeople = $_POST['numberofpeople'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$cardtype = $_POST['cardtype'];
$cardnum = $_POST['cardnum'];
$specialrequests = $_POST['specialrequests'];

  $DOCUMENT_ROOT = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
?>
<html>
<body>
<?php
//displays what the user put in the form by using the vairables
 echo "<table>";
 echo '<h1>Thank you '.$fname.' '.$lname.' for your Reservation</h1><br>';
echo 'The following is the infomation you entered:<br></tr>';
echo "<tr><td>Number & Street</td><td>$address</td><br/</tr>"; 
echo "<tr><td>City</td><td>$city</td><br></tr>"; 
echo "<tr><td>ZipCode</td><td>$zip</td><br></tr>"; 
echo "<tr><td>State</td><td>$state</td><br></tr>"; 
echo "<tr><td>Check-In Date</td><td>$indate</td><br></tr>"; 
echo "<tr><td>Check-out Date</td><td>$outdate</td><br></tr>"; 
echo "<tr><td>Number of People</td><td>$numberofpeople</td><br></tr>"; 
echo "<tr><td>Phone</td><td>$phone</td><br></tr>"; 
echo "<tr><td>Email</td><td>$Email</td><br></tr>"; 
echo "<tr><td>Card-Type</td><td>$cardtype</td><br></tr>"; 
echo "<tr><td>Card-Number</td><td>$cardnum</td><br></tr>"; 
echo "<tr><td>Special Requests</td><td>$specialrequests</td><br></tr>"; 
echo  "</table>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: code has some mistakes. That's why you got an incorrect output. do you need a verbal answer or the correct code as an answer

Comment: If you could point me in the right direction that would be much appreciated

Comment: hope this answer will help you that

Comment: You need to match your opening and closing tags for starters. The line with `h1` doesn't have an opening `<tr>` but has a closing `</tr>`. Then, you have `</td><br/</tr>` line breaks between `td` and `tr` for an unknown reason, with possibly unpredictable results. Try fixing those for starters.

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php

// create short variable names
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$zip = $_POST['zip'];
$state = $_POST['state'];
$outdate = $_POST['outdate'];
$indate = $_POST['indate'];
$numberofpeople = $_POST['numberofpeople'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$cardtype = $_POST['cardtype'];
$cardnum = $_POST['cardnum'];
$specialrequests = $_POST['specialrequests'];

$DOCUMENT_ROOT = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
?>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Thank you <?php echo $fname." "; ?><?php echo $lname; ?> for your Reservation</h1><br>
<h2>The following is the infomation you entered:</h2><br>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Number & Street</td>
    <td><?php echo $address; ?></td>
</tr>
... complete other in this fashion
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Inside the table, you put a h1 tag

some tags were not hadn't an enclosing tag at some lines.

Make sure that your code has lots of vulnerabilities. please learn some good programming techniques to implement your code

[image]
Complete the other tables rows.

Comment: Sahan, this didn’t fix the gap in-between the "The following is the infomation you entered:” and the “address” sections. if its ok with you could i get a bit more assistance on it

Comment: I update it. extract this and complete table rows for others

Comment: *"Make sure that your code has lots of vulnerabilities"* that. Are there any examples of input filtering or other checks in your code?